# Removing the duplicate values in a column but keeping the first duplicate one for a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

I've a CSV file that looks like :

```
Timestamp  Status
1501       Normal
1501       Normal
1502       Delay
1503       Received
1504       Normal
1504       Delay
1505       Received
1506       Received
1507       Delay
1507       Received
```

I was able to add a new "Notif" column to dataframe that appears as a counter variable and has an increment when it comes across the "Received" value in the "Status" column. I've the output now like :

```
Timestamp  Status     Notif
1501       Normal     N0
1501       Normal     N0
1502       Delay      N0
1503       Received   N1
1504       Normal     N1
1504       Delay      N1
1505       Received   N2
1506       Received   N3
1507       Delay      N3
1507       Received   N4
```

Now I want to remove all the duplicate values in the column, keeping the first one. I want the output as :

```
Timestamp  Status     Notif
1501       Normal     N0
1501       Normal     
1502       Delay      
1503       Received   N1
1504       Normal     
1504       Delay      
1505       Received   N2
1506       Received   N3
1507       Delay      
1507       Received   N4
```

For the first output with N0, N0, N0, N1, N1, N1, N2, N3, N3, N4 I used the code :

```
df['Notif'] = None
counter = 0
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if df.iloc[idx, 1] == "Received":
        counter +=1
    df.iloc[idx,-1] = "N" + str(counter)
```

For removing the duplicate values part I used :

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='Notif', keep="first")
```

After running my code for removing the duplicates, it seems that the "Notif" column gets a strange numerical value of 400 throughout.

Comment: `df.Notif = np.where(df.Notif.duplicated(), np.NaN, df.Notif)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for any loop (as in the other answer).
You can do it with a **single** instrction:

```
df.Notif = df.Notif.mask(df.Notif.duplicated(), '')
```

`df.Notif.duplicated()` generates a *bool* series, marking duplicated values,
except the first one (default value of *keep* is just *first*).

Then it is used as the condition in *mask*, which sets the empty string
(second argment) in elements indicated by *True* values.

I assume that you want in this rows just the **empty string**, not *NaN*
as proposed in one of comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could just have the assignment be part of the loop where the string of "Received" is found. Then you wouldn't have to remove any strings, but only add it on the correct rows.

```
df['Notif'] = None
counter = 0
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if df.iloc[idx, 1] == "Received":
        counter +=1
        df.iloc[idx,-1] = "N" + str(counter)
```

Comment: If you want the default value to be an empty string, then just replace the None with empty quotes.